# How to create an iterable object from a WikipediaPage object?

Tags: python-3.x, wikipedia

I'm trying to change a document ranker from a project that needs a model that takes a huge amount of memory to be trained to a simpler one based on `wikipedia` library.

From  queries, a list of query that contains only one query at the moment

```
queries : ['What is the population of Toulon']
```

I would like to change the way it was ranked to the closest doc using `wikipedia.page()` function. Yet for the good functioning of this ranker I know that I need an interable object at the end. Indeed I tried

```
    # Rank documents for queries.
    if len(queries) == 1:
        # ranked = [self.ranker.closest_docs(queries[0], k=n_docs)]
        ranked = [wikipedia.page(queries),wikipedia.page(queries)] # which is stupid I know, but don't know how to do it differently yet.
    all_docids, all_doc_scores = zip(*ranked)
```

and got an `all_docids, all_doc_scores = zip(*ranked) TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration` error.

Until now I have two wikipedia pages :

```
<WikipediaPage 'Toulon'> <WikipediaPage 'Toulon'>
```